# Angular - How to control display on another client

Tags: node.js, angular

I am a very beginner in angular. I am making a Kahoot like application. This has 2 views (admin view and player view). How do I control display on player view from admin view? My requirement is that when I click "show question" button on admin view, I want to display that question on players' view. I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Look at [Socket.io](https://socket.io/get-started/chat) and its [angular module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io)

Comment: You could use rxjs websocket instead of the Socket.io library.

Comment: or peer.js if you wont to develop a websocket backend solution.